# Getting "Cannot GET /login" when sending a file from a post request in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send a new html to the user if they succesfully login. Whenever I try to send a file I always see "Cannot GET /login" on the page.

Here is the piece of code giving me trouble:

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var acc = {};
  var data = req.body
  acc.username = data.username
  acc.password = data.password

  fs.readFile('storage.json', (err, jsonData) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let acc = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    let authenticated = false;
    for(var i=0; i<acc.accs.length; i++){
      if(acc.accs[i].username == acc.username && acc.accs[i].password == acc.password){
        authenticated = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(authenticated){
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/homepage.html'))
    } else {
      res.send("fail")
    }
  });
});
```

There is no problem with the HTML form, I've tried changing that already.

Apologies if this is a simple question with a simple answer, I am new to node/express development.

Comment: The message indicates that the client is sending a GET request, but the code shown is expecting a POST request.  Which are you trying to perform?

Comment: Post the code that makes the request please.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that after successful login, your homepage.html might have some resources (like CSS or JS files) which are not correctly linked. When browser tries to get those resources, it might be hitting the "/login" route with a GET request, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

So the message is `Cannot GET /login`

But in the code I see that you define a route to `/login` with `POST` HTTP method in the first line

```js
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
```

Seems the problem is on the client side, they should use the `POST` method

```html
<form method="POST" ... >
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: literally said in the original post there is no problem with the html

Comment: So why are you getting this error `Cannot GET /login`?
It's saying `GET`, if the request were right it would say something like `Cannot POST /login`
Or you should define a route in `app.get('/login' ...`

Comment: You should check @MasYasinArafat 's answer
Since your code does not persist the user session, just defining another route wouldn't get protected by the authentication